# Add a link to a form with jQuery (userscript) in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a search link to an online form with a userscript using jQuery. I don't work too much in firefox and I feel like things that would normally work in chrome don't in ff 9/10 times for me. But anyway... this needs to be with ff.

I'm taking the text from a `<p>` element and creating a search url out of it (or trying to). Right now this is the function I'm trying that should be doing it... but it's doing nothing, not even any errors in console

```
$(function() {

    var companyName = $('p')[7]; // Element that contains the name text
    var companyText = companyName.text(); // Retrieve the text from element
    var mixRankUrl = $("<a></a>").innerHTML("Search Mixrank"); // Create an <a> element
    mixRankUrl.href = 'https://mixrank.com/appstore/sdks?search=' + companyText; // Define the href of the a element
    var sdkPara = $('label.control-label')[10]; // Where I want it to go
    sdkPara.append(mixRankUrl); // Append the element
});
```

Also, whoever wrote the html uses hardly any ids, and most classes are assigned to 10 or more elements... so unless there's a better way, I'm sort of stuck using node selectors (which stay the same form to form).

Comment: `I feel like things that would normally work in chrome don't in ff 9/10 times for me` It's your feeling. In the real world, firefox is the only that fits with standards, and chrome preffers his `-webkit-` prefixes for all the tasks. You should visit MDN sometimes :)

Comment: So there is something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you try to use jQuery method on DOM element. Don't understand why you don't have any errors with your code.
For exemple : `$('p')[7]` return a DOM element while `$('p').eq(7)` return a JQuery object. So you can't use a jQuery method like `text()` on your DOM element. You need to deal with jQuery object.

For the same reason, you had a problem with the declaration of your label object and with the modification of the href attribute of your link.

Try like this :

```
$(function() {
  var companyName = $('p').eq(7); // Element that contains the name text
  var companyText = companyName.text(); // Retrieve the text from element
  var sdkPara = $('label.control-label').eq(10); // Where I want it to go
  var mixRankUrl = $('<a>',{
     text: 'Search Mixrank',
     href: 'https://mixrank.com/appstore/sdks?search=' + companyText
  }).appendTo(sdkPara); // Append the element
});
```

Comment: That worked! Why wouldn't my original way work vs this?